# How to make my website not become distorted when I zoom in and out?

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website and I was wondering how I can make my website not to distort when I zoom in a and out. Zooming at 150% makes all the navigation buttons get all clustered up causing them to overlap each other. I tried using media tags which proved to work well with other devices, however, it does not seem to work when zooming in and out. (NOTE: This is my first ever website so you cna understand my confusion). Here is my code:

HTML & CSS:

```css
*{
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  box - sizing: border - box;
  font - family: Century Gothic;
}

header {
  height: 15 % ;
  background - size: cover;
  background - position: center;
  background - color: #ebebeb;
  border - bottom: 5 px solid# A9A9A9;
}

@media(min - width: 768 px) and(max - width: 991 px) {
  header {
    height: 8 % ;
  }
}

@media(min - width: 768 px) and(max - width: 1199 px) {
  header {
    height: 13.5 % ;
  }
}

@media(min - width: 960 px) and(max - width: 1400 px) {
  header {
    height: 11.5 % ;
  }
}
html,
body {
  /*  background: #000000;*/
  font - size: .80e m;
  /* font-family: "Balsmiq", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;*/
  margin: 0 % ;
  padding: 0 % ;
  color: #696969;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

    /*Carousel*/

    .carousel-container {
    width: 70%;
    max-height: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid white;
    }

    .carousel-slide {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    }

    # prevBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40 % ;
    z - index: 10;
    left: 20 % ;
    font - size: 50 px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #
  prevBtn: hover {
    color: black;
  }

  #
  nextBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40 % ;
    z - index: 10;
    right: 20 % ;
    font - size: 50 px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #
  nextBtn: hover {
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo-text">
      <h1 class="text-logo">TITLE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <!--Image Slider-->

  <div class="back-color">
    <div class="carousel-container">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
      <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="Could not load">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" id="first" alt="Could not load">
        <img src="./img/testpic2.jpg" alt="Could not load">
        <img src="./img/testpic3.jpg" id="last" alt="Could not load">
        <img src="./img/testpic1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="Could not load">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There reason I included the Image slider is because it distorts aswell. When I zoom out you are able to view the other pictures which I have hidden.

Any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: was I able to solve your issue? Or you need any other sort of help also? Kindly let me know!

Answer (score 1):

What I think is the problem with that zooming, is, that you have specified the dimensions in percentage because of what your elements change themselves according to undefined dimensions. If you will use `px` or `vw` problem will be resolved... VW and VH are also percentages but they haves a ratio with the view port's dimensions, which prevent them from distorting their shapes on zoom. That's my take on it!

`%` are relative to parent elements,
whereas, `vw` and `vh` are relative to view port.

Check this link for more [info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: if I was able to solve your problem, then kindly accept my answer

Comment: Yes. I have tried that, using vh and vw and it still seems to distort. This is confusing